# Testing a Formik Error Message Component Using Jest & React Testing Library

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, formik

I am testing that when I click continue on my web app, it renders the diners option error message on the screen. formik forms are asynchronous and so I added async, await and the waitFor terminology to ensure that they are able to make updates to the state. I continue to get an error, cannot find an element with the text: * Please Select the Amount of Diners.

```
test('it shows 4 required fields', async () => {
    const user = userEvent.setup()
    
    user.click(screen.getByTestId('continue'))
    
    const diners = await screen.findByText('* Please Select The Amount of Diners');

    await waitFor(() => {
         expect(diners).toBeInTheDocument('* Please Select The Amount of Diners');
    })
})
```

this is the diners part of my formik form

```html
<Field 
     label="NoOfDiners" 
     className= {errors.NoOfDiners && touched.NoOfDiners ? "input--error": "form--button"}
     as="select" name="NoOfDiners" 
     placeholder="NumberOfDiners" 
     data-testid="NoOfDiners" 
     aria-errormessage="error-diners" 
     aria-invalid="true"
     >
     <option value="">Diners</option>
     <option value="1">1</option>
     <option value="2">2</option>
     <option value="3">3</option>
     <option value="4">4</option>
     <option value="5">5</option>
     <option value="6">6</option>
     <option value="7">7</option>
     <option value="8">8</option>
  </Field>
     <ErrorMessage component="div" className="error--diners" name="NoOfDiners" id="error-diners" />
```

I have tried these:

- I saw some articles which added async in the waitFor() method:

  ```
    await waitFor(async() => {
       await expect(diners).toBeInTheDocument('* Please Select The Amount of Diners');
     });
  ```

  or

  ```
     await waitFor(async() => {
       await diners.toBeInTheDocument();
     });
  ```
- I tried to resolve the expect

  ```
    expect(Promise.resolve(diners)).toBeInTheDocument();
  ```

  this leaves a: cannot convert undefined or null to object
- I tried not having async in the waitFor method and using toHaveAccessibleErrorMessage():

  ```
    await waitFor(() => {
      expect(diners).toHaveAccessibleErrorMessage('* Please Select The Amount of Diners');
    });
  ```

Comment: `const diners = await screen.findByText(...)` (**not** `async`, that's a syntax error) _already_ waits for the element to be found, with a specific timeout. If that fails to resolve, the `waitFor` is never even reached.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Apologies. This was a type error whilst writing the question; it was not in my code.  I continue to have the same issues. If there are any other suggestions you may be able to give me, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide a minimal reproducible example? From your code it is not clear how the error is produced.